# Why does .NET Core Worker Service has two different exception behaviors in ExecuteAsync method?

Tags: c#, service, worker

I created a sample .NET Core worker serivce in below, it just threw an Exception.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DemoWorkerService
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                throw new Exception("My Exception");

                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above worker service process will be aborted due to the exception threw as expected.

Then I changed the Exception put it after the await statement as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DemoWorkerService
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);

                throw new Exception("My Exception");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This time the worker service process is still ongoing after the exception has been thrown, I can even stop the process in console by pressing "Ctrl+C", here is the log information:

```
info: DemoWorkerService.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 01/16/2020 12:26:07 +08:00
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\MyProjects\DemoWorkerService\DemoWorkerService
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

It seems like the worker service captured the exception by itself this time, so the exception was not 
propagated to outer process, I don't know why the worker service will have different behaviors, which I put the exception before and after await? Is there any reason that worker service has such two different exception behaviors?

Comment: Learn more about async/await and you will see that in these two cases the exceptions are from different threads and handled differently.

Comment: @LexLi I know the continuation of await will work on a different thread pool thread. But I want to know why .NET Core worker service treate such two exceptions in different attitudes?

Comment: Unhandled exceptions are treated differently when they come from different threads. A program usually crashes when such exceptions come from a thread other than the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. `BackgroundService` implements `IHostedService` and only returns from `StartAsync` when your service has [begun execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class).

If any `IHostedService` throws an exception during `StartAsync`, then the `IHost` will fail to start.

So if your `BackgroundService` throws before the first await, the exception will propagate and fail the host. If you want to prevent this, you can simply call `await Task.Yield()` first.

Comment: Does it mean any exception throw after StartAsync will be captured by worker service itself, so the process won't be afftected. But any exception throw in the StartAsync will cause the worker service process to be aborted, since it is an unhandled exception?

Comment: More specifically, starting an `IHost`will fail if any registered `IHostedService` fails to start. It's `BackgroundService` that has a slightly weird semantics in this case.